# Custom UILabel with gradient text colour always become black

Tags: swift, text, colors, uilabel, gradient

I created a custom UILabel to show grediant text but it always show the text as black...when i but the same code on a view controller it works!!

```
import UIKit

class GradientLabel: UILabel {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let gredient = GradientView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
        gredient.bottomColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)
        gredient.topColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1)
        setTextColorToGradient(image: imageWithView(view: gredient)!)
    }


    func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {//bet7awel uiview to image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }

    func setTextColorToGradient(image: UIImage) {//beta7'od image we tekteb beha el text fe el label
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
        image.draw(in: bounds)
        let myGradient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        textColor = UIColor(patternImage: myGradient!)

    }

}
```

Comment: If you make a label in code, awakeFromNib is never called.

Comment: Also your frame is being fetched too early.

Comment: try this library: https://github.com/darincon/MaskedLabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t want to rely on `awakeFromNib`. Furthermore, you really don’t want to do this in `init`, either, as you want to be able to respond to size changes (e.g. if you have constraints and the `frame` changes after the label is first created).

Instead, update your gradient from `layoutSubviews`, which is called whenever the view’s `frame` changes:

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1) {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1) {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateTextColor()
    }

    private func updateTextColor() {
        let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds).image { _ in
            let gradient = GradientView(frame: bounds)
            gradient.topColor = topColor
            gradient.bottomColor = bottomColor
            gradient.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }

        textColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }

}
```

That results in:

[image: example label]

Note,

- I’ve used the new `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` rather than `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.
- Rather than building a `CGRect` manually, I just use `bounds`.
- I’ve made it `@IBDesignable` so that I can use it directly in Interface Builder. I’ve also made the colors `@IBInspectable` so you can adjust the colors right in IB rather than going to code. Clearly, you only have to do this if you want to see the gradient effect rendered in IB.
- I’ve made it update the gradient (a) when the label needs to be laid out again; and (b) whenever you change either of the colors.

---

For what it’s worth, this is the `GradientView` I used for the purposes of this example:

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }

    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() } }
    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = .blue { didSet { updateColors() } }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        updateColors()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        updateColors()
    }

    private func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    }

}
```

In this case, because we’re setting the `layerClass` to the gradient, all we need to do is to configure it during `init`, and the base `layerClass` will take care of responding the size changes.

---

Alternatively, you can just draw your gradient using CoreGraphics:

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1) {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1) {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateTextColor()
    }

    private func updateTextColor() {
        let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds).image { context in
            let colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
            guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors as CFArray, locations: nil) else { return }
            context.cgContext.drawLinearGradient(gradient,
                                                 start: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY),
                                                 end: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY),
                                                 options: [])
        }

        textColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }

}
```

This achieves the same as the first example, but is potentially a tad more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and professional clarification...it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You should `init` your label instead of `awakeFromNib` cause you are not using a xib for your label

```
class GradientLabel: UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

and an extension would be perfect to make your code reusable

```
extension UILabel {
   func setTextColorToGradient(_ image: UIImage) {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
      image.draw(in: bounds)
      let myGradient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      textColor = UIColor(patternImage: myGradient!)
   }
}
```

usage:

```
label.setTextColorToGradient(UIImage(named:"someImage")!)
```